# Excel source in SSIS Package has a password

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

So an SSIS job has been failing because the source file, an excel file, has a password on it.

Would we be the best way to ensure that the password is being used in the SSIS package? Thanks!

Comment: You can't: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017#excel-file. Your file must not be passworded for it to be used as a source by SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't open directly a password protected Excel file with SSIS with the standard connection.

A solution would be writing a custom Script Task (with C# or VB), opening the file with an Excel library like NPOI, EPPlus or Interop (or many other probably) and generating the output of the flow manually.

Another solution would be using 3rd parties SSIS connection adapters.

Worth mentioning that a workaround would be removing the password first with any utility (like powershell) and using the password-free resulting excel in your Excel connection manager on SSIS.